# Can a single iCloud account store WhatsApp backups from two phone numbers?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

We are from the UK and had a phone stolen two days ago, we are in South Africa for another month.

The UK network provider is sending another SIM to our UK address as it can’t be activated from abroad. So we have bought a new phone in SA, restored it from an iCloud backup and using a local SIM card.

We don’t want to lose the WhatsApp chats we had, so have opted not to install WhatsApp on the new phone (SA number) until we get back and can put in the new SIM. It’s a pain as WhatsApp would be useful from here. Although I’m now wondering whether we can in fact use WhatsApp with the new number now without losing the old chats in iCloud and then restore the old chats when we’re back in the UK and on the UK number.

Can iCloud store backups to two different WhatsApp numbers? As each one is specific to a phone number and not the Apple ID I’d have thought so but I don’t want to risk losing data.

Answer (score 4):

> Can iCloud store backups to two different WhatsApp numbers?

**No**.

If and when you perform a backup of WhatsApp chat on iCloud, it overrides any previous backup.

If you wish to regain access to your old (original) chat once you have access to the new SIM for the original number, it's advised that you don't perform any backup over iCloud with the new (temporary) SIM installed.

Comment: Thank you! We’ve got a work phone here, so we’ve put the local card back in that and using WhatsApp on that phone without being signed into iCloud so that there are no new backups

Answer (score 0):

[According to WhatsApp's FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/618575946635920/?cms_platform=iphone), that's possible:

> Because backups are tied to individual phone numbers, it is possible to have backups for multiple WhatsApp accounts stored in the same iCloud account.